# Trouble adding SQL tables in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with update 3. So when I try to add a new table on the server explorer, it doesn't give me the option to.

For example, before, above the Refresh and Properties button, it had a "Add new table" button. **Any idea why it has disappeared?**

Tried reinstalling Visual Studio

[image]

Comment: what if you close down vs2013 and re-open it as `Administrator` does that help

Comment: It looks like that you are allowed to read data, but not meta data. Can you get dbo rights for the database?

Comment: Tried opening up in Administrator, no luck. I cannot open up an already created table neither, it just doesn't give me the option. On my laptop though it works perfectly. (Option that are not there on my PC are there on my laptop...)